# C++ multiple inheritance reading from file save object twice

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

first let me explain my hierarchy :

```
         Animal
       /    |   \
   Mammal  Fish  Birds  
   /    \ /        \
Horse   MammalFish Flamingo
         /     \
    Mermaid   GoldFish
```

Each class has the following methods :

```
Save(ofstream & ofs) // Saves the data to txt file
Load(ifstream & ifs) // Load the data from txt file
Constructor(ifstream & ifs) { Load(ifs) } // Constructor from file, uses `Load` method.
```

Each class implement its own Load/Save method (if they have any data members) and calls the prior class in the hierarchy Load/Save method .

The problem is with my multiple inheritance, when I use `Mermaid` or `GoldFish` Save method, it saves animal twices (which basically makes sense) , but I can't find a way to avoid this..

Another problem is with the constructor , its automatically calls all the base classes default constructor(which is unwanted, should only call `Load()` which calls the base class methods) . I can't explicitly call the base class constructors , because in my `Load()` method I also call the base class `Load()` methods, which will make me use `Load()` twice.

Thanks.

Comment: The keyword is *virtual inheritance* which was introduced exactly for this use case.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I use virtual inheritances , the animal object is only created once. The `Load()` method is being used twice

Comment: Ah, I see. You must solve the issue which the language takes care of in the case of constructors for a different method. I suppose the solution is similar as for the ctors of virtual bases: The most derived class is responsible for calling the ctor, and also responsible for loading. Neither is nice because ideally Mermaid would prefer not to deal with her (more than once removed) base classes directly.

Comment: There is no easy way ro avoid this. You may mark subobject that are already saved/restored, which requires you to pass a set of pointers to subobjects around.

Comment: You may also consider using the boost serialisation library.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual inheritance should solve the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) that is there for `MammalFish` in your inheritance tree. Also it demands that you declare both Load and Save methods be virtual if they are going to be in all the classes.

For the constructor issue, every child class constructor will call the base class construct first to ensure base class is initialized properly; this is how inheritance works. In your case you may consider not calling `Load` from constructor. Instead it should be called from a separate initialize method.

Answer (score -1):

Something came to mind which I admittedly never heard of before, so it may be a bad idea, but anyway; this should work:

Follow each `load()` call with an `endLoad()`  call. Each object performs only one `load()` in a sequence of `load()`s and ignores subsequent ones until an `endLoad()` is encountered.

Comment: I'd appreciate any critique.